# scrollbar with image in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

i'm getting an unexpected vertical scrollbar when resizing the window when I have an image in a flexbox container.
The image has a max-width and max-height in a flex:1 column flexbox container.
All is good in some window ratios, but if the window is small in height, I get a vertical scrollbar, with some blank space under the image.

Any ideas why?

CSS

```
body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin:0;
    height:100vh;
}
#cont{
    flex:1;
}
#cont img{
    max-width:80%;
  max-height:80%;
}
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cont">
    <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2547/4011378891_ca862aeb8f_b.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/sym8qb4t/

Resize the window in height and a scollbar will appear at some point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for the unexpected behaviour is to add:

```
  overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: yeah thanks this solution crossed my mind but it doesn't explain why I get that scrollbar in the first place... Looks like a dirty fix to me (effective, but dirty...)
Plus it doesn't solve that white space under the image.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Have an image always covering 80% of the available viewport?

Comment: By bad for the comment about blank space with this overflow:hidden fix, it "solves" the issue. I upvote your answer, even if I still don't understand the behavior.

Comment: @okp As I tried to tell you in my comment, you can find all the documentation to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size -->. The solution is to add `min-height:0;` to your `#cont` div.

Comment: @ReSedano sorry I missed your comment. Indeed, duplicate then. Thanks!

Comment: @okp No problem. You're welcome! :-)